# 'For transformation matrices, the rank of matrix tells you the dimensions of the output.' What does this statement mean?

Tags: matrices, transformation, matrix-rank

Kindly explain in simple terms because I have limited knowledge of matrices. 
Also, what is a transformation matrix?

Answer (score 0):

A transformation matrix is just a matrix. The word transformation emphasises that the matrix can take you from a (vector) space with one dimension (say 3D space) into another one (say 2D space). Going from 3D space into 2D space requires a matrix of 3 columns of 2 numbers each. Each of these 3 columns is 2D and after applying the matrix to the column $(x, y, z)$ you get a 2D column. This resulting column of numbers is a linear combination of the columns of the original matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 1&  3& 2 \\ 
 2& 1 & 5
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{bmatrix}=x\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
2
\end{bmatrix}+y\begin{bmatrix}
3\\ 
12
\end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 
5
\end{bmatrix}$$
The columns of the matrix thus describe all possible outcomes of the transformation in 2D. All three of these columns cannot be independent of each other - we must be able to write one of them as a combination of the other 2. Sometimes we might be able to do more - maybe  two of them are multiples of the other. The rank of the matrix is the number of independent columns and as the output in 2D is a combination of these columns its dimension must be this rank.